# Issue in ggplot with continuous x axis as year

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think this should be simple but I am running into an issue I can't seem to fix.

I am trying to show each Region as a different line across multiple years with the value being total profit. However, I always get the image below.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

```r
 dput(head(sales,90))
    structure(list(Region = c("Sub-Saharan Africa", "Europe", "Middle East and North Africa", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa", "Europe", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Asia", 
"Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Central America and the Caribbean", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa", "Europe", "Europe", "Central America and the Caribbean", 
"Middle East and North Africa", "Australia and Oceania", "Central America and the Caribbean", 
"Europe", "Middle East and North Africa", "Europe", "Asia", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Asia", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Australia and Oceania", 
"Central America and the Caribbean", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Europe", "Central America and the Caribbean", "Middle East and North Africa", 
"Middle East and North Africa", "Europe", "Sub-Saharan Africa", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Middle East and North Africa", "Europe", 
"Middle East and North Africa", "Europe", "Europe", "Australia and Oceania", 
"Australia and Oceania", "Australia and Oceania", "Europe", "Australia and Oceania", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Asia", "Sub-Saharan Africa", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Central America and the Caribbean", "Europe", 
"Middle East and North Africa", "Central America and the Caribbean", 
"Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Sub-Saharan Africa", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa", "Sub-Saharan Africa", "Europe", "Sub-Saharan Africa", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa", "Europe", "Asia", "Central America and the Caribbean", 
"Asia", "Middle East and North Africa", "North America", "Sub-Saharan Africa", 
"Sub-Saharan Africa", "Europe", "Europe", "Sub-Saharan Africa", 
"Europe", "Sub-Saharan Africa"), Country = c("Chad", "Latvia", 
"Pakistan", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Czech Republic", 
"South Africa", "Laos", "China", "Eritrea", "Haiti", "Cameroon", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Germany", "Barbados", "Algeria", "Palau", 
"Cuba", "Vatican City", "Lebanon", "Lithuania", "Myanmar", "Ukraine", 
"Russia", "Japan", "Russia", "Liechtenstein", "Slovakia", "Albania", 
"Federated States of Micronesia", "Dominica", "Andorra", "Switzerland", 
"Lithuania", "San Marino", "Nicaragua", "Azerbaijan", "Syria", 
"Serbia", "Mauritius", "Germany", "Italy", "Bhutan", "Turkey", 
"Bulgaria", "Pakistan", "Poland", "France", "Fiji", "Australia", 
"Nauru", "Slovenia", "Samoa", "South Africa", "Ghana", "Sri Lanka", 
"Guinea", "Spain", "Moldova", "Dominican Republic", "Luxembourg", 
"Kuwait", "Saint Lucia", "Georgia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", 
"Iceland", "Mauritius", "Malawi", "Seychelles", "Montenegro", 
"Germany", "Estonia", "Serbia", "Madagascar", "Benin", "Hungary", 
"Djibouti", "Senegal", "Ireland", "Mongolia", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
"Cambodia", "Oman", "United States of America", "Mauritania", 
"Central African Republic", "Albania", "Switzerland", "Ghana", 
"Austria", "Democratic Republic of the Congo"), Item_Type = c("Office Supplies", 
"Beverages", "Vegetables", "Household", "Beverages", "Beverages", 
"Vegetables", "Baby Food", "Meat", "Office Supplies", "Cereal", 
"Baby Food", "Office Supplies", "Vegetables", "Clothes", "Snacks", 
"Beverages", "Beverages", "Personal Care", "Snacks", "Meat", 
"Office Supplies", "Snacks", "Cosmetics", "Meat", "Vegetables", 
"Cereal", "Baby Food", "Baby Food", "Beverages", "Office Supplies", 
"Personal Care", "Clothes", "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Cosmetics", 
"Baby Food", "Beverages", "Fruits", "Meat", "Cereal", "Clothes", 
"Clothes", "Cosmetics", "Household", "Cereal", "Baby Food", "Beverages", 
"Personal Care", "Office Supplies", "Cosmetics", "Clothes", "Cereal", 
"Vegetables", "Office Supplies", "Meat", "Fruits", "Personal Care", 
"Cereal", "Personal Care", "Office Supplies", "Fruits", "Vegetables", 
"Cosmetics", "Snacks", "Personal Care", "Office Supplies", "Meat", 
"Personal Care", "Household", "Meat", "Clothes", "Baby Food", 
"Beverages", "Clothes", "Snacks", "Fruits", "Household", "Meat", 
"Baby Food", "Personal Care", "Vegetables", "Baby Food", "Office Supplies", 
"Cosmetics", "Baby Food", "Vegetables", "Household", "Vegetables", 
"Household"), Sales_Channel = c("Online", "Online", "Offline", 
"Online", "Online", "Offline", "Online", "Online", "Online", 
"Online", "Offline", "Offline", "Online", "Offline", "Offline", 
"Offline", "Online", "Online", "Offline", "Offline", "Online", 
"Online", "Offline", "Offline", "Offline", "Offline", "Offline", 
"Offline", "Online", "Offline", "Online", "Online", "Offline", 
"Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Offline", 
"Online", "Offline", "Offline", "Online", "Offline", "Offline", 
"Offline", "Offline", "Online", "Online", "Offline", "Online", 
"Offline", "Online", "Online", "Offline", "Online", "Offline", 
"Online", "Online", "Online", "Offline", "Online", "Offline", 
"Offline", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", "Online", 
"Online", "Offline", "Online", "Offline", "Offline", "Online", 
"Offline", "Offline", "Offline", "Online", "Online", "Online", 
"Online", "Offline", "Offline", "Offline", "Online", "Online", 
"Online", "Online", "Offline"), Order_Priority = c("L", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "H", "L", "C", "L", "C", "M", "M", "C", "C", "C", 
"L", "H", "L", "H", "H", "C", "C", "L", "H", "L", "L", "H", "C", 
"M", "H", "M", "M", "M", "H", "L", "M", "L", "H", "H", "L", "H", 
"L", "L", "L", "M", "C", "M", "L", "H", "H", "M", "C", "M", "L", 
"M", "C", "L", "M", "L", "L", "L", "C", "H", "H", "H", "M", "C", 
"C", "L", "L", "H", "M", "C", "H", "M", "H", "H", "H", "L", "H", 
"H", "C", "L", "L", "H", "H", "M", "M", "H", "L"), Order_Date = c("1/27/2011", 
"12/28/2015", "1/13/2011", "9/11/2012", "10/27/2015", "7/10/2012", 
"2/20/2011", "4/10/2017", "11/21/2014", "7/4/2015", "1/1/2016", 
"10/20/2012", "2/22/2015", "1/1/2016", "6/21/2011", "9/19/2013", 
"11/15/2015", "4/6/2015", "4/12/2010", "9/26/2011", "1/2/2016", 
"8/14/2010", "4/13/2012", "9/19/2013", "12/2/2015", "2/26/2017", 
"1/2/2016", "5/20/2011", "10/24/2013", "6/14/2011", "6/20/2015", 
"8/5/2011", "1/2/2016", "7/5/2015", "3/25/2015", "8/22/2013", 
"1/3/2016", "6/23/2013", "5/8/2015", "1/3/2016", "3/10/2013", 
"3/18/2012", "2/11/2015", "10/30/2012", "7/6/2012", "1/4/2011", 
"10/25/2013", "1/3/2016", "3/16/2014", "1/3/2016", "9/30/2010", 
"11/5/2010", "7/21/2017", "7/10/2013", "10/6/2012", "6/4/2011", 
"4/12/2014", "10/26/2015", "8/4/2011", "2/24/2017", "3/30/2011", 
"5/2/2015", "2/1/2014", "3/3/2012", "4/22/2015", "5/12/2011", 
"12/21/2011", "12/2/2010", "8/14/2010", "10/5/2010", "2/8/2012", 
"9/8/2012", "8/11/2011", "10/28/2012", "10/11/2013", "1/3/2016", 
"7/28/2017", "1/5/2016", "1/5/2016", "11/13/2014", "8/26/2012", 
"7/15/2014", "5/2/2011", "11/11/2013", "4/14/2011", "10/4/2012", 
"5/14/2013", "1/12/2013", "10/3/2012", "10/23/2010"), Order_ID = c(292494523, 
361825549, 141515767, 500364005, 127481591, 482292354, 844532620, 
564251220, 411809480, 327881228, 743598735, 479823005, 498603188, 
953377091, 181401288, 500204360, 640987718, 206925189, 221503102, 
878520286, 319358670, 746630275, 246883237, 967895781, 305029237, 
223957431, 485685670, 121455848, 332936227, 692031657, 365978467, 
392325484, 917994248, 603977954, 965943562, 233629691, 664174449, 
212921321, 763686978, 520714461, 637702119, 671986758, 912333714, 
540041816, 156722390, 434299266, 765008771, 593408763, 856333482, 
682830178, 574837148, 365692222, 289660394, 681165492, 594943845, 
956044280, 509828126, 771969211, 178453862, 835580909, 869961678, 
278519999, 478492200, 257427108, 723186051, 353942859, 848183858, 
374707877, 322626245, 351362788, 640653836, 540548217, 821407258, 
523904788, 109027135, 113437545, 672654092, 701131856, 148230302, 
230407607, 129491746, 606854999, 885983693, 260676658, 345045220, 
123513209, 900816953, 452005279, 672439515, 827793490), Ship_Date = c("2/12/2011", 
"1/23/2016", "2/1/2011", "10/6/2012", "12/5/2015", "8/21/2012", 
"3/20/2011", "5/12/2017", "1/10/2015", "7/20/2015", "2/18/2016", 
"11/15/2012", "2/27/2015", "1/3/2016", "7/21/2011", "10/4/2013", 
"11/30/2015", "4/27/2015", "5/19/2010", "10/2/2011", "1/16/2016", 
"8/31/2010", "4/22/2012", "9/28/2013", "12/26/2015", "2/28/2017", 
"1/10/2016", "6/19/2011", "12/3/2013", "7/20/2011", "7/21/2015", 
"9/1/2011", "1/16/2016", "7/29/2015", "5/9/2015", "8/30/2013", 
"1/27/2016", "7/18/2013", "5/13/2015", "1/25/2016", "4/4/2013", 
"5/4/2012", "3/2/2015", "11/3/2012", "8/1/2012", "2/21/2011", 
"12/10/2013", "2/20/2016", "4/27/2014", "2/15/2016", "11/11/2010", 
"12/5/2010", "8/22/2017", "7/26/2013", "10/21/2012", "7/24/2011", 
"4/15/2014", "12/15/2015", "8/27/2011", "4/14/2017", "4/12/2011", 
"6/14/2015", "2/26/2014", "4/10/2012", "5/13/2015", "5/15/2011", 
"1/18/2012", "12/25/2010", "9/16/2010", "11/14/2010", "3/18/2012", 
"9/20/2012", "8/19/2011", "11/7/2012", "10/27/2013", "1/10/2016", 
"7/31/2017", "2/11/2016", "1/26/2016", "12/20/2014", "9/22/2012", 
"8/15/2014", "5/4/2011", "12/17/2013", "5/20/2011", "11/21/2012", 
"6/10/2013", "2/2/2013", "11/12/2012", "11/20/2010"), Units_Sold = c(4484, 
1075, 6515, 7683, 3491, 9880, 4825, 3330, 2431, 6197, 6245, 9145, 
6618, 4322, 9527, 441, 1365, 2617, 6545, 2530, 4182, 3345, 7091, 
725, 3784, 2835, 4038, 339, 2083, 6401, 16, 6684, 3753, 9353, 
3020, 5072, 2834, 7005, 803, 9835, 9083, 4670, 8675, 9229, 6493, 
7659, 1950, 1695, 6962, 3479, 5941, 5310, 5802, 861, 5959, 3603, 
8327, 1699, 7318, 5814, 9848, 9112, 5330, 7257, 5678, 8412, 5307, 
3243, 1130, 4912, 2562, 9084, 1516, 3924, 2407, 7545, 2148, 9352, 
3495, 1586, 8340, 735, 1118, 8871, 5403, 9158, 609, 7261, 8650, 
1344), Unit_Price = c(651.21, 47.45, 154.06, 668.27, 47.45, 47.45, 
154.06, 255.28, 421.89, 651.21, 205.7, 255.28, 651.21, 154.06, 
109.28, 152.58, 47.45, 47.45, 81.73, 152.58, 421.89, 651.21, 
152.58, 437.2, 421.89, 154.06, 205.7, 255.28, 255.28, 47.45, 
651.21, 81.73, 109.28, 154.06, 9.33, 437.2, 255.28, 47.45, 9.33, 
421.89, 205.7, 109.28, 109.28, 437.2, 668.27, 205.7, 255.28, 
47.45, 81.73, 651.21, 437.2, 109.28, 205.7, 154.06, 651.21, 421.89, 
9.33, 81.73, 205.7, 81.73, 651.21, 9.33, 154.06, 437.2, 152.58, 
81.73, 651.21, 421.89, 81.73, 668.27, 421.89, 109.28, 255.28, 
47.45, 109.28, 152.58, 9.33, 668.27, 421.89, 255.28, 81.73, 154.06, 
255.28, 651.21, 437.2, 255.28, 154.06, 668.27, 154.06, 668.27
), Total_Profit = c(566105, 16834.5, 411291.95, 1273303.59, 54669.06, 
154720.8, 304602.25, 319213.8, 139053.2, 782371.25, 553244.55, 
876639.7, 835522.5, 272847.86, 699662.88, 24316.74, 21375.9, 
40982.22, 164017.7, 139504.2, 239210.4, 422306.25, 390997.74, 
126055.75, 216444.8, 178973.55, 357726.42, 32496.54, 199676.38, 
100239.66, 2020, 167501.04, 275620.32, 590454.89, 7278.2, 881868.64, 
271667.24, 109698.3, 1935.23, 562562, 804662.97, 342964.8, 637092, 
1604646.23, 1076084.89, 678510.81, 186927, 26543.7, 174467.72, 
439223.75, 1032961.67, 389966.4, 513999.18, 54354.93, 752323.75, 
206091.6, 20068.07, 42576.94, 648301.62, 145698.84, 1243310, 
21959.92, 336482.9, 1261774.59, 313084.92, 210804.72, 670008.75, 
185499.6, 28317.8, 814065.76, 146546.4, 667128.96, 145323.76, 
61449.84, 176770.08, 416031.3, 5176.68, 1549906.96, 199914, 152033.96, 
209000.4, 46400.55, 107171.48, 1119963.75, 939419.61, 877885.88, 
38446.17, 1203365.53, 546074.5, 222741.12), Month_RecentYear = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "January", NA, NA, "January", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "January", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "January", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "January", NA, NA, NA, "January", NA, NA, 
"January", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "January", NA, "January", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "January", NA, "January", 
"January", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Year = structure(c(14975, 
16436, 14975, 15340, 16436, 15340, 14975, 17167, 16071, 16436, 
16801, 15340, 16436, 16801, 14975, 15706, 16436, 16436, 14610, 
14975, 16801, 14610, 15340, 15706, 16436, 17167, 16801, 14975, 
15706, 14975, 16436, 14975, 16801, 16436, 16436, 15706, 16801, 
15706, 16436, 16801, 15706, 15340, 16436, 15340, 15340, 14975, 
15706, 16801, 16071, 16801, 14610, 14610, 17167, 15706, 15340, 
14975, 16071, 16436, 14975, 17167, 14975, 16436, 16071, 15340, 
16436, 14975, 14975, 14610, 14610, 14610, 15340, 15340, 14975, 
15340, 15706, 16801, 17167, 16801, 16801, 16071, 15340, 16071, 
14975, 15706, 14975, 15340, 15706, 15706, 15340, 14610), class = "Date"), 
    Month = c("January", "December", "January", "September", 
    "October", "July", "February", "April", "November", "July", 
    "January", "October", "February", "January", "June", "September", 
    "November", "April", "April", "September", "January", "August", 
    "April", "September", "December", "February", "January", 
    "May", "October", "June", "June", "August", "January", "July", 
    "March", "August", "January", "June", "May", "January", "March", 
    "March", "February", "October", "July", "January", "October", 
    "January", "March", "January", "September", "November", "July", 
    "July", "October", "June", "April", "October", "August", 
    "February", "March", "May", "February", "March", "April", 
    "May", "December", "December", "August", "October", "February", 
    "September", "August", "October", "October", "January", "July", 
    "January", "January", "November", "August", "July", "May", 
    "November", "April", "October", "May", "January", "October", 
    "October"), RDate = structure(c(15001, 16797, 14987, 15594, 
    16735, 15531, 15025, 17266, 16395, 16620, 16801, 15633, 16488, 
    16801, 15146, 15967, 16754, 16531, 14711, 15243, 16802, 14835, 
    15443, 15967, 16771, 17223, 16802, 15114, 16002, 15139, 16606, 
    15191, 16802, 16621, 16519, 15939, 16803, 15879, 16563, 16803, 
    15774, 15417, 16477, 15643, 15527, 14978, 16003, 16803, 16145, 
    16803, 14882, 14918, 17368, 15896, 15619, 15129, 16172, 16734, 
    15190, 17221, 15063, 16557, 16102, 15402, 16547, 15106, 15329, 
    14945, 14835, 14887, 15378, 15591, 15197, 15641, 15989, 16803, 
    17375, 16805, 16805, 16387, 15578, 16266, 15096, 16020, 15078, 
    15617, 15839, 15717, 15616, 14905), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -90L))
```

```
ggplot(sales, aes(x= as.Date(Year), y=Total_Profit, group=Region, col=Region)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Most of the data is not needed to reproduce the question. However, it was useful to understand the problem. There are repeating values for `Year`, so of course you are getting vertical lines. Maybe you want to use `RDate` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to plot `RDate` instead. `Year` has repeating values. The lines are all a bit crowded - an option may be to facet them:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(sales, aes(x= as.Date(RDate), y = Total_Profit, group=Region, col=Region)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~ Region, ncol = 1)
#> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust
#> the group aesthetic?
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: that would work I believe. However, I tried the code you used and got this picture. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjJvkX9tcVyvgZoaQADb2IZXJ35mcg?e=1padV3

Any idea why that might be? thank you!

Comment: @josephl that looks good to me  - what do you think is wrong?

Comment: Ahh I realize now I only gave you a sample of the data in the dput so of course your graph looks cleaner. I guess to rephrase my question. I don't want to plot each individual order. I want to sum up the total profit per year for each region and then have a different line for each region showing how sales per year change over time. I realize now I could probably just make a few calculated columns in excel and do it that way but I didn't know if R made it easier some way.